# Using Java Runtime class to run multiple unix commands

Tags: java, unix

I am trying to use Runtime class to execute some UNIX commands but I am getting issues if I try to use `cd` command.

Here is my Java program:

```
import java.io.*;

public class JavaRunCommand {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String s = null;

        try {

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd;cat test.txt|grep Hello");

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                 InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                 InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            // read the output from the command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            // read any errors from the attempted command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("exception..");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

If I execute this then I am getting an exception as:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    at JavaRunCommand.main(JavaRunCommand.java:11)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
    ... 4 more
```

Please let me know how can we run multiple commands if I want to use it in Java.

Comment: `cd` is not a binray. It is a shell builtin command.

Comment: `cd` is an arg passed to the executable `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Use ProcessBuilder rather than Runtime.exec.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Answer (score 3):

If you replace

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd;cat test.txt|grep Hello");
```

with

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/bin/sh", "-c", "cd && cat test.txt | grep Hello" });
```

it should do.

As cd is a built-in shell command you need to call your shell to execute it. When using windows you would require to call `"cmd /c"`.

Answer (score 2):

`cd` is a built-in shell command for traversing directories. It's therefore not an actual unix command that can be run in the way you're trying.

The easiest solution is to use absolute paths in the commands you are calling. E.g., instead of trying to run `"cd /my/dir; cat test.txt"` simply call `"cat /my/dir/test.txt"`.

Answer (score 0):

As you asked how to run multiple commands and gave `cd;cat test.txt|grep Hello` as an example, you need `sh` to process your command, because it is not a single executable program.

Despite of security implications (*), you can do

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh -c 'cd;cat test.txt|grep Hello'");
```

(*) It is generally considered as a bad security practice as unwanted commands can be executed depending on environment